# Syncfusion win phone AdornmentsInfo text cuts from chart edges

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, bar-chart, syncfusion

I have a `BarSeries`-Chart and want to show `Y`-Value on top of it.

I have used `AdornmentsInfo` but text cuts down from right edge of my chart. I checked win phone documentation for `AdornmentsInfo` and they're also in picture.

Text cuts from top edge of chart.

Is there any way to fix this, because it's not looking good.

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid the edge label adornment cropping by setting PlotOffset property for the chart axis as below

Code Snippet[C#]:

chart:NumericalAxis PlotOffset="20">

Regards,

Sheik